ui-select Multiple Dropdown Search Input Spinner Not Showing
I am working with an AngularJS project, where I upgraded the library from ui-select2 to ui-select. After the upgrade, I'm having issues with the search input spinner not showing for multiple select dropdowns, although it works fine for single select dropdowns.
Html
<ui-select multiple ng-if="list.edit" ng-model="list.EmployeeList" theme="select2" class="col-xs-12">
   <ui-select-match allow-clear="true" placeholder="Select People for Delivery">{{$item.Name}}-{{$item.EmployeeCode}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices refresh="selectOptionsEmployeeWithoutRelievingPromise($select.search)" refresh-delay="500" repeat="item in EmployeesWithoutRelieving">
       {{item.Name}}
    </ui-select-choices>
   <div ui-select-no-choice class="no-match-message">No matches found</div>
</ui-select>

The spinner shows correctly when using theme="bootstrap", but not when using theme="select2".
Css
/*Custom css gif loader for search input*/
.ui_select_input_spinner .ui-select-search{
    background-image: url('../../areas/commoncontrols/scripts/fileviwer/content/css/select2-spinner.gif');
    background: url('../../areas/commoncontrols/scripts/fileviwer/content/css/select2-spinner.gif') no-repeat 100%, -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.85, #fff), color-stop(0.99, #eee));
    background: url('../../areas/commoncontrols/scripts/fileviwer/content/css/select2-spinner.gif') no-repeat 100%, -webkit-linear-gradient(center bottom, #fff 85%, #eee 99%);
    background: url('../../areas/commoncontrols/scripts/fileviwer/content/css/select2-spinner.gif') no-repeat 100%, -moz-linear-gradient(center bottom, #fff 85%, #eee 99%);
    background: url('../../areas/commoncontrols/scripts/fileviwer/content/css/select2-spinner.gif') no-repeat 100%, linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff 85%, #eee 99%) 0 0;
}
/* Hide the search icon when loading */
.ui_select_input_spinner div.search-container.select2-search::after {
    visibility: hidden; /* or display: none; */
}

Problem Description
The above CSS works fine for a single dropdown, but it doesn't work for the multiple dropdown. I suspect the issue lies in how the class is applied, and I need to generalize it so that it works for both single and multiple select dropdowns.
JavaScript (select.js)
ctrl.refresh = function (refreshAttr) {
    if (refreshAttr !== undefined) {
        // Debounce
        if (_refreshDelayPromise) {
            $timeout.cancel(_refreshDelayPromise);
        }
        // Automatically add the 'loading' class
        $element.addClass('ui_select_input_spinner'); // Add the 'loading' class
        _refreshDelayPromise = $timeout(function () {
            if ($scope.$select.search.length >= $scope.$select.minimumInputLength) {
                var refreshPromise = $scope.$eval(refreshAttr);
                if (refreshPromise && angular.isFunction(refreshPromise.then) && !ctrl.refreshing) {
                    ctrl.refreshing = true;
                    refreshPromise.finally(function () {
                        ctrl.refreshing = false;
                        $element.removeClass('ui_select_input_spinner'); // Remove the 'loading' class when refresh completes
                    });
                } else {
                    $element.removeClass('ui_select_input_spinner'); // Remove the class if there's no promise
                }
            } else {
                $element.removeClass('ui_select_input_spinner'); // Remove the class if input length is not met
            }
        }, ctrl.refreshDelay);
    }
};


Expected Outcome
I expect the spinner to show while fetching the results in both single and multiple ui-select dropdowns. Currently, the spinner only appears for single dropdowns, but not for multiple dropdowns.

please share the full directive and other selects you are using

@Naren Murali Thanks for your response! The issue isn’t with the directive itself, but rather how the CSS class is applied. The spinner class ui_select_input_spinner works perfectly for a single dropdown, but it doesn’t apply properly for multiple.
I suspect the multiple attribute might be affecting how the class is being applied.
I want to generalize the solution so that the spinner class works for both single and multiple dropdowns without having to manually add it every time.
Let me know if you think the multiple attribute or something else in the directive could be the issue!

Minimal reproducible code is needed, you have not shared the minimal code needed, sorry its difficult for others to check. Best if you provide a working example on stackoverflow editor.

@Naren Murali Thanks for the feedback. I understand the need for a minimal reproducible example, but unfortunately, I can't share the entire code due to the complexity of the software. The app interacts with a large Huawei database via an AJAX call, and it’s not feasible to replicate that in a simple example.

setTimeout emulates an API call, require basic working code, not all the complicated stuffs

@Naren Murali I understand. The challenge is that the select.js code is part of a larger library, and it's quite large. It wouldn't be feasible to paste the entire library here.

@Naren Murali Thanks for your understanding! I appreciate your suggestions
